# how can reply wordpress comment programmatically

Tags: wordpress

in WORDPRESS, when need to add comment use this function:

```
wp_insert_comment();
```

but, after add the comment, I need to add reply to comment programmatically, there is way for this?

Answer (score 1):

The WP_Comment Object has a parent property on it. Give the ID of the comment you're replying to, as the parent ID for this comment.

```
wp_update_comment(['comment_ID' => {{REPLYING_COMMENT_ID}}, 'comment_parent' => {{REPLYING_TO_COMMENT_ID}}, 'comment_content' => 'My new comment.']);
```

We can use the wp_update_comment() function to update a comment array with all the data we need.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_comment/

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Fires immediately after a comment is inserted into the database.
 *
 * @since 2.8.0
 *
 * @param int        $id      The comment ID.
 * @param WP_Comment $comment Comment object.
 */
do_action( 'wp_insert_comment', $id, $comment );
```

You could hook into wp_insert_comment and just ignore a specific user of the comment id if their role is administrator. For example;

```
If( author of comment id user privileges != 'administrator' ) {
//insert reply
}
```